# What is the logic when functions access outside variables in python

Tags: python

As expected, the Case 1 works.

Case 1:

```
num = 5

def print_():
    print(num)

print_()
```

The case 2, however, doesn't work.

Case 2:

```
file1.py
--------------
def print_():
    print(num)

file2.py
--------------
from file1 import *

num = 5
print_()
```

If the function is defined in another file and imported, it doesn't work.
I cannot figure out the reason why.
In my thought, when the function is run, the global variable is already in existence,
so there should be no difference between the two cases.

Comment: It's only global in the module.